# How do I dynamically load a CSS file in a TMS WEB Core Website using Delphi?

Tags: css, delphi, dynamic, tms, tms-web-core

What's the best way to dynamically insert CSS files into my TMS WEB Core website using Delphi?

I want to load a certain CSS file depending on the theme (dark/light). So whenever the website opens, then it needs to dynamically load the correct CSS file.

How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 0):

The [`TApplication`](https://download.tmssoftware.com/doc/tmswebcore/gettingstarted/application/) class has an `InsertCSS` and `RemoveCSS` function that can be used for this.

So as an example, let's say I want to dynamically load Bootstrap into my application with a button click, I could do this:

```
procedure TfrmMain.WebButton1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Application.InsertCSS('MyCSS', 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css');
end;
```

You could also do this directly in the `.dpr` file such as:

```
program TestApp;

{$R *.dres}

uses
  Vcl.Forms,
  WEBLib.Forms,
  uIndex in 'uIndex.pas' {frmMain: TWebForm} {*.html};

{$R *.res}

begin
  Application.Initialize;
  Application.MainFormOnTaskbar := True;
  Application.CreateForm(TfrmMain, frmMain);

  Application.InsertCSS('MyCSS', 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css');

  Application.Run;
end.
```

Running the above examples would insert the following line of code into the `<head>` tag on your page:

```
<link id="MyCSS" rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

Comment: No, that's a DOM node, not "code". Why is the attribute `id` added? Why do you use an arbitrary keyword for `rel` instead of [adhering HTML and using `stylesheet`](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/links.html#link-type-stylesheet)?

Comment: @AmigoJack Ah. That was a typo. Nice catch. Thanks. I fixed it.